# Angular 2 : defining a Router on another Component than the bootstraped one

Tags: javascript, routes, typescript, angular

I'm still working on a project using Angular2.
If you want more details about why I need to do what I'm going to explain, please refer this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328035/angular2-systemjs-cannot-find-module-while-building-a-moduleloader).

I have an `AppComponent` which is bootstraped via `bootstrap`. It's a very simple component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-view',
    directives: [ Devtools, MainComponent ],
    template: `
        <ngrx-devtools></ngrx-devtools>
        <main-cmp></main-cmp>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This component includes another one : `MainComponent` (via the `main-cmp` selector). For some reasons, I want to set up my routing in `MainComponent`.

Here is the code :

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'main-cmp',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavComponent ],
    template: `
        <h1>App</h1>
        <nav-cmp></nav-cmp>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home',    name: 'Home',   component: HomeComponent,   useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/medias',  name: 'Medias', component: MediasComponent }
])
export class MainComponent {
    constructor (private router:Router, private store:Store<AppStore>) {
        router.subscribe(url => store.dispatch(changeUrl(url)));
    }
}
```

Finally, `MainComponent` includes `NavComponent` which is a very basic nav.

The thing is, with this setup, I encounter this issue : 
`EXCEPTION: Component "AppComponent" has no route config. in [['Home'] in NavComponent@2:15]`.

Of course, if I move my router's logic to `AppComponent`, everything works well.

So my question is : is there a way to do routing stuff into another component than the one which is bootstraped ?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that it's not possible because the `generate` method of the `RouteRegistry` class explictly relies (hardcoded) on the root component. See this line in the source code:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/route_registry.ts#L345

Here is the code that trhows the error:

```
RouteRegistry.prototype._generate = function(linkParams,
         ancestorInstructions, prevInstruction, _aux, _originalLink) {
  (...)
  var parentComponentType = this._rootComponent; // <----
  (...)

  var rules = this._rules.get(parentComponentType);
  if (lang_1.isBlank(rules)) { // <----
    throw new exceptions_1.BaseException("Component \"" +
      lang_1.getTypeNameForDebugging(parentComponentType) +
      "\" has no route config.");
  }

  (...)
};
```

This method is indirectly used from the `_updateLink` method of the `RouterLink` directive.

Here is the corresponding stack trace:

```
RouteRegistry._generate (router.js:2702)
RouteRegistry.generate (router.js:2669)
Router.generate (router.js:3174)
RouterLink._updateLink (router.js:1205)
```

See the plunkr I used to debug your problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/8JojtgZmc8kA9ib6zvKS?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

How about a workaround - use root as a child route?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/...', as: 'Main', component: MainComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])
export class App { }

@Component({ 
    selector: 'main-cmp',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    template: `
        <h1>App</h1>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home',    name: 'Home',   component: HomeComponent,   useAsDefault: true },
])
export class MainComponent { }
```