# Angular2 TypeError: linkParams.forEach is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to navigate to a route explicitly from a function on click event

```
<a (click)="loadContact()">Contact</a>
```

`AppComponent` class is defined this way

```
export class AppComponent{

    constructor(private _router:Router){}

    public loadContact = function(){
        ...
        ...
        this._router.navigate('[Contact]');
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: linkParams.forEach is not a function
```

How do I fix it?

EDIT:

Here is the RouteConfig

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/contact', name: 'Contact', component: ContactsComponent },
    { path: '/notes', name: 'Notes', component: NotesComponent }
])
```

Comment: Post `Contact` route config?

Comment: Can you show AppComponent's `@Component` decorator and `bootstrap()` ?

Comment: It works if I use `<a [routerLink]="['Contact']">Contact</a>` but that is not what I want. I need to do some stuff when I select contact option from the menu

Comment: No more code needed. The call to `navigate` is wrong 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `TypeError: linkParams.forEach is not a function`

Error cause : `When a redirect, or router link is setup incorrectly and an array is not provided, an error is thrown`

Reported to provide better error handling too : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7952

## Your code

Here :

```
this._router.navigate('[Contact]');
```

Is a string. It should be :

```
this._router.navigate(['Contact'] /* some array */);
```

## More

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array

Comment: Oh! that worked.. I changed it to `this._router.navigate(['Contact']);`

Comment: please have a look at this question. need help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483722/angular2-nested-routing-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
 this._router.navigate(['Contact']);
```